# OpenAM install cannot create default configuration, error in OpenDS

Tags: openam, forgerock

Have installed OpenAM 14.5.4 on Tomcat and CentOs7 with a few basic Ansible steps. Just building a proper Ansible playbook step by step.
However 'Create default configuration' from the WebUI keeps on failing at OpenDJ, and
our Forgerock developer with whom I'll be completing the work only has time next year.
So maybe someone encountered this already?

==============
Install.log in /home/tomcat/openam

```
2/18/2020 12:48:21:265 PM UTC: Extracting OpenDJ, please wait...
12/18/2020 12:48:21:563 PM UTC: Complete
12/18/2020 12:48:21:563 PM UTC: Running OpenDJ setup
12/18/2020 12:48:21:563 PM UTC: Setup command: --cli --adminConnectorPort 5444 --baseDN dc=openam,dc=openidentityplatform,dc=org --rootUserDN cn=Directory Manager --ldapPort 51389 --skipPortCheck --rootUserPassword xxxxxxx --jmxPort 2689 --no-prompt --doNotStart --hostname 1.1.1.34 --noPropertiesFile --backendType je

Configuring Directory Server .....

Error Configuring Directory Server.
See /opt/tomcat/temp/opendj-setup-12499578588005068186.log for a detailed log
of the failed operation.
Please report this error and provide the log file mentioned above.

To see basic server configuration status and configuration, you can launch
/home/tomcat/openam/opends/bin/status

12/18/2020 12:48:22:967 PM UTC: ...Failed.
12/18/2020 12:48:22:967 PM UTC: ...Failed 5
```

=========================
Then

```
/home/tomcat/openam/opends/bin/status

          --- Server Status ---
Server Run Status:        Stopped
Open Connections:         <not available> (*)

          --- Server Details ---
Host Name:                bkd-revgem-proxy.bkd.local
Administrative Users:     cn=Directory Manager
Installation Path:        /home/tomcat/openam/opends
Version:                  OpenDJ Server 4.4.8
Java Version:             <not available> (*)
Administration Connector: Port 4444 (LDAPS)

          --- Connection Handlers ---
Address:Port : Protocol : State
-------------:----------:---------
--           : LDIF     : Disabled
0.0.0.0:389  : LDAP     : Enabled
0.0.0.0:636  : LDAPS    : Disabled
0.0.0.0:1689 : JMX      : Disabled
0.0.0.0:8080 : HTTP     : Disabled

          --- Data Sources ---
Base DN:     dc=openam,dc=openidentityplatform,dc=org
Backend ID:  userRoot
Entries:     <not available> (*)
Replication: 

* Information only available if server is running and you provide val
```

===============
And file /opt/tomcat/temp/opendj-setup-12499578588005068186.log (and .log.lck) were created with size 0 :-(

=================
As it helped solving some earlier also the /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       bkd-revgem-proxy.bkd.local      bkd-revgem-proxy
# This file is managed by Ansible, all changes will be lost.
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
10.0.2.15 bkd-revgem-proxy bkd-revgem-proxy
1.1.1.5 bkd-awx awx
1.1.1.34 bkd-revgem-proxy.bkd.local
1.1.1.34 bkd-revgem-proxy

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Thanks in advance! Erik

Comment: OpenAM 14.5.4 is not from ForgeRock but a fork from https://www.openidentityplatform.org/

Comment: Which FQDN did you use to configure OpenAM 14.5.4?

Comment: Oops, won't refer to ForgeRock anymore if it's just a fork ;-) Anyhow this version was mentioned in the ForgeRock github, that's why I used it from Ansible.

On the 2nd question: I just deployed openam.war to the /opt/tomcat/webapps, I never explicitiy configured an FQDN. And for the health check used the IP adress, 1.1.1.34. Due to another error in creating Default configuration I added the two possible FQDN's of the machine in the hosts file, see above. But if you tell I should have added some other config, you're welcome ;-) Thanks in advance...

Comment: I doubt it's mentioned in ForgeRock github. OpenAM community edition was Forgerock but now others are using this 'name' as well and this is really confusing.

Comment: When you configured OpenAM (either via GUI or `configurator.jar`, what did you specify as server URL?

Comment: Okay the link to https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM/releases/download/14.5.4/OpenAM-14.5.4.war  came from a Forgerock site, but agree that this github part itself is not from Forgerock. I did not 'configure' OpenAM with a site, I solely copied the WAR to the Tomcat Webapps directory and then restarted Tomcat, But maybe best if you tell where that FQDN should be stored in the config, then if I did not supply the config file yet in the thread I can add it? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

In your install log i see:

```
--cli --adminConnectorPort 5444,
```

However when using status, i see that your admin port is 4444, so make sure you use the same port.